# How can i export a chart as jpg?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to export an specific print area with macros, but when execute the code, it exports a white jpg.
If i set a breakpoint at paste line and execute the code it works.
Any idea?

Thats my code:

```
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
sFilePath = "C:\Users\test.jpg"    
zoom_coef = 100 / sheet.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom
Set area = sheet.Range(sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
area.CopyPicture xlPrinter
Set chartobj = sheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
chartobj.Chart.Paste '<- if i set the breakpoint here it works, if not, it returns a white jpg
chartobj.Chart.Export sFilePath, "jpg"
chartobj.Delete
```

i expect a jpg with the print area but it returns a jpg without anything.

Comment: Why are using the `Application.Wait` call? Possibly has to do with that some way

Comment: Try using `Application.Wait` after the line `chartobj.Chart.Paste` instead and see if that works for you.

Comment: Try making the chart active with `chartobj.activate` before pasting and exporting.